# What is a PHP variable without quotes

Tags: php

here's my question:

What is a PHP variable/string without quotes? Below is the code I wrote and went wrong:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];

$query = "DELETE FROM email_list WHERE email = $email";
```

the correct code should be:

```
$query  = "DELETE FROM email_list WHERE email = '$email'";
```

So, variable $email is not a string without quotes, even if it's what I input in the form?

Then I wrote a code in PHP:

```
echo($email."<br />");
echo("$email" ."<br />");
```

The result turned out to be same in the browser.
So why should I add another single quotes to enclose $email while it's already enclosed by double quotes?

Comment: Have you tried echoing the queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing `$email` and `"$email"` outputs the same. Writing `"'$email'"` doesn't.

In the last case, you are adding a single quote before and after; which are needed by SQL to recognize a string.

If the creators of the SQL language had decided that strings had to be enclosed between `#` you would have to write `"#$email#"` if you want the SQL engine to recognize the string. It has nothing to do with how PHP treats or interpolates strings; it has to do with SQL.

Comment: Understood, your anwser is very clear, thanks!!!

Comment: I just ran into something like this today. `"INSERT INTO MyTable (Date, IPAddr, Key, CID, Version) VALUES (NOW(),'$ipAddr','$key','0','$pixels')"` if $pixels does not have the single quotes around it, then only a numeric value is allowed.